# responsive image not working on safari mac and safari iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

im making a website, but the responsive image for safari mac/iphone is not working
here is my code

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="es">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Reparación iPhone – iPad, iPod | iFixed</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<nav><a href="http://www.ifixed.mx"><img src="LayerMain.png" style="max-width: 100% height: auto" /></a></nav>
```

and this is the css

```
 img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: What is happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i need the image fit only in the window, not going outside, it only does it on android browser

Comment: the image is the header

Comment: Can't reproduce on Safari 10.1: https://jsfiddle.net/85v1pzgm/

Answer (score -1):

For most 'resposive' images in layout, here's how I'd recomend setting that up. The parent should define the constraints.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/9dnjvnc4/

```
<figure class='logo'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/800x700' alt='example image'>
</figure>
```

...

```
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; /* reset */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%; /* just in case? not nessesary */
}

.logo { /* specific figure size */
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

It sounds like you are trying to get a full-screen image - in which case you should use background-image on a div setup to be full-screen or the body etc. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/v65saLmd/

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/2400x4000');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: is not a fullscreen imagen just a header image

Comment: not working either, [Link](http://ifixed.mx/es/cotiza)    i have done everything you suggested me

Comment: You don't have the correct styles applied to the img. When I add them in the developer tools they work. Good luck! : )

Comment: i have done everything you suggested me in jsfiddle, im not web developer but still having the issue, any other suggestion?